# update shopping cart status into another open page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, shopping-cart

In shopping cart web application I need to update another opened page cart status. Problem is something like this: Suppose user added something into cart then he opened another page for seeing other products, now 2nd page showing updated cart. So if user add another product from 2nd page then I need to update 1st page cart status also. How can I update 1st page cart status using only javascript and without refreshing the first page ?

Edit 1: There is a dirty way, which is I can do it by polling, by sending a get request after 2/3 seconds interval. But there must be some other better way.

Comment: you can store cart items as cookies but you still have to periodically poll the cookies to check for new items

Comment: Well this is definitely better solution than mine. Thanks.